# Clarifying proof of result in a field

Tags: proof-verification, field-theory

Question:

Let $F = \{0,1,a,b\}$ be a field with four elements. Prove that $a^2 = b$.

My answer:

Case 1:

If $a \cdot a = a$ then $a=1$, not possible.

Case 2:

If $a \cdot a = 0$ then $a=0$, not possible.

Case 3:

**For case 3 my textbook says:**

If $a^2=1$, then $a^2=a \cdot b$, and we can multiply both sides by $a^{-1}$ to get $b=1$, which is impossible.

**For case 3 I say:**

We know that $a \cdot b = 1$ in this field. So, if $a \cdot a = 1$ then $a \cdot a = a \cdot b$.

$$a^{-1} \cdot (a \cdot a) = a^{-1} \cdot (a \cdot b)$$
$$(a^{-1} \cdot a) \cdot a = (a^{-1} \cdot a) \cdot b$$
$$1 \cdot a = 1 \cdot b$$

$a = b$, which is not possible.

---

For case 3 the textbook got $b = 1$ contradiction and I am getting $a = b$ contradiction. Why are we getting different contradictions? How did the textbook get $b = 1$ as a contradiction? Is my method for case 3 wrong?

Comment: you're correct, book is wrong. good on you for keeping a skeptical eye open!

Comment: In case 1 there are two distinct solutions to the quadratic. The other solution is 0.

Comment: Please don't include text in the formulas, i.e. don't write `$some text and formula$` but instead `some text and $formula$`. I'll edit your post to correct this.

Comment: Not putting text inside `$...$` will also make you not have to put a backslash before every space.